Easy way to autonomous periodic data update in Laravel, PHP
How can I autonomous calculate and update value for one column in my Laravel project? I have no much experience in web-dev, so I just dont how to do it effective.
For example, now I've column "Condition" that calculates every time user open main page, I know its a dumb solve, so I want to update this "Condition" column every time when column "Count" (just any count) was changed and do it autonomous. I thought about events and listeners, but have too few information about how correctly communicate with this in my case.
In C#, for example, it was too easy, just subscribe to any event and do what u want. Here I need something likes columnWasChanged('Count') -> so call event/listener handler.
Thanks!
I tried:
//...Controllers\MyController.php

public function index() {
    ...
    ...
    event(new UpdateConditionEvent($request));
    ...
}

//...Listeners\ConditionUpdateListener.php

public function handle(UpdateConditionEvent $event) {
    //...updatuing...
}

UPD: "Count" is a column in the DB too, like a "Condition". And as I said, "Condition" column is calculating in php code, for example any formula: $condition = $currentCondition - ($entry->Count / 100000) * 100; doesn't matter.
So I need to update "Condition" exactly in DB by SQL every time, when "Count" DB column was changed, i.e. I think I cant use SQL triggers.
About it - "Count" is changing by microcontroller request every 60 second, I thought it's not important, so I'm sorry.

If this is a column in your SQL database, you could use a SQL Trigger to detect that update and then run some more SQL to update another column, for example. But it wasn't clear if "condition" is a column in your database, or just a value which is being calculated on-demand by your PHP code, for displaying only on a specific page. Nor was it particularly clear if "count" is a column in the database either, or something else. Nor do we know what things can cause it to be changed. Can we have a bit more context please? See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue.You can [edit] your post

In C#, for example, it was too easy, just subscribe to any event...it's not clear what this means either. What kind of C# app? What sort of event, exactly? Are you talking about a desktop app, perhaps? Really a web app has similar operational constraints no matter what language it's written in.

@ADyson,
Done.
@
Yes, I was talk about C# dekstop app, sorry, as I said before I have a little exp in web-dev. I didnt work with ASP.NET so I dont know how to implement this task in .NET web app, but I know how to do it in dekstop app.

So I need to update "Condition" exactly in DB by SQL every time, when "Count" DB column was changed, i.e. I think I cant use SQL triggers...but that's exactly what SQL triggers can do - they can automatically detect when a row is changed, and then update other fields or tables based on that. The simple maths you're doing in the PHP could also be done in SQL.

So if you write the Count value into the database, a SQL trigger would notice that, and the trigger code can do the calculation to update the Condition column for that same row

You can overload the save() method in the model to check if the 'count' is dirty(changed) before saving and trigger the event in that case.

@ADyson, I'll try, thanks! Just never used triggers

Well, it's always good to learn something new!
